# Don't repaint instantly after setVisble in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm using [QPushButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QPushButton.html) in my mineSweeping game.

After changing from easy mode to hard mode, the number of *QPushButton* is supposed to change from 9x9 to 30x16.

So, I add *QPushButton* with the largest number(which is of hard mode) to *GridLayout* in constructor of *MainWindow*.

```
btnArr = new QPushButton[HARD_WIDTH * HARD_HEIGHT]; // member element
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < HARD_HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < HARD_WIDTH; ++j) {
        ui->mainGrid->addWidget(&btnArr[index], i, j, 1, 1,
                                Qt::AlignCenter);
        ++index;
    }
}
```

Then if the user change mode(e.g.: easy mode to hard mode), `resetBtn(HARD_WIDTH, HARD_HEIGHT);` will be called.

```
void MainWindow::resetBtn(const int width, const int height)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < HARD_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HARD_WIDTH; ++j) {
            if (j < width && i < height) {
                btnArr[index].setVisible(true);
            } else {
                btnArr[index].setVisible(false);
            }
            ++index;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it seems the widget repaints each time `setVisible` is called. So in the hard mode case, it will be called 30x16 times, which caused strange effect like this:
[image]

So how can I set the widget not repaint during this loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of `QPushButton` is really big: 30x16 = 480!!! I don't use to make people change their programming logic, but in this case I think that using `QPushButton`s is not the better approach. The layout must have a really bad time trying to move the objects as they are added, and perhaps you are reaching some internal limit in refresh time for the layout to be repainted.

What I would have done is a custom widget with a custom `paintEvent` method. There you can divide its width and height in the number of columns and rows that you wish and paint the cells with pixmaps as the game is played.

For the mouse interaction, the best would have been to override the `mousePressEvent` with a custom logic that calculates the mouse position in the grid and calls the corresponding methods or emits signals indicating the position of the event. Not very hard to code. You can also use the `event->buttons()` method to know which mouse button was pressed and emit different signals if you wish.

I don't use to answer telling that it is better to change your whole program, but in this case I think you are going "the hard way". I know this is not the kind of answer you are looking for, but consider this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are trying to solve the wrong problem. You shouldn't be updating the widgets like this. If you necessarily want to, then hiding the parent widget of the layout before the change and showing it again afterwards should work.

A better approach is to use [QStackedWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) and have all the boards prepared initially. Switching to a different board is then simply a matter of switching the active widget.

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling [`setUpdatesEnabled(false)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop) on the parent widget before doing those "massive" changes, and re-enable it once all is done.

Comment: The parent widget of them is a gridWidget, which doesn't have `setUpdatesEnabled(false)` method. The parent widget of gridWidget is MainWindow. I tried on it but nothing changed.

Comment: _All_ objects that derive from QWidget have that method. What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: It is an instance of QGridLayout, and does not derive from QWidget. Qt Version is 4.7.4 with MinGW 4.4 compiler

Comment: Call that on the parent _widget_, not layout. If you're using QMainWindow, call it on the central widget.

Comment: I used central widget, but nothing changed. Did it work on your machine?

Comment: There's a bug in your second function: `for (int j = 0; j < HARD_WIDTH; ++i) {` - should be `j++`. Yes, this already worked for me, but I didn't try to reproduce your exact code. If you want someone to do that, post a minimal, complete piece of code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong but as far as I know Qt doesn't render the widget right after setVisible() is called. Rendering happens as a result of a 'render' event, except if you call render() manually.

From the official Qt doc (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#paintEvent):

> Qt also tries to speed up painting by merging multiple paint events
>   into one. When update() is called several times or the window system
>   sends several paint events, Qt merges these events into one event with
>   a larger region (see QRegion::united()). The repaint() function does
>   not permit this optimization, so we suggest using update() whenever
>   possible.

My instincts tell me that it's not a painting problem rather a layouting (not enough space to present every button in 'hard mode'). 
Also I think you shouldn't use Qt::AlignCenter when you add your buttons to the layout, it will try to centerize every button in the layout. You should rather centerize the parent widget of the layout (if you don't have one create one and centerize it) and set size-policies correctly (QWidget setSizePolicy).

But as @Mat suggested if this really is a painting problem you can use setUpdatesEnabled(false/true) (if setUpdatesEnabled solves your problem please accept @Mat 's solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enabling/disabling instead of visible/invisible:

```
void MainWindow::resetBtn(const int width, const int height)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < HARD_HEIGHT; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < HARD_WIDTH; j++)
            btnArr[index++].setEnabled(j < width && i < height);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I need. Is it proper to display unenabled buttons in mine game?

Comment: @Ovilia, try call button->setFlat(true) - so your button will be invisible))